# What permissions to grant power-users on Tasks list?

Tags: 2013, permissions, tasks, inheritance, workflow-tasks-list

What is the proper way to give power users the ability to see ALL workflow tasks on a site? Is breaking inheritance on the list itself a bad idea?

I'm not sure if that can mess up user permissions for normal users seeing/completing their own tasks. Right now, if I put a test user in the Full Control group, that lets them see all tasks but is obviously too privileged.

```
/apps/SiteName/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

To "see" items in lists such as a task list the default "Read" permission level works. Then the higher permissions you go the more users can edit and interact with content, list, site etc.

Breaking permissions causes more places in your site to keep track of and manage so more groups and permissions inheritance usually better.

Workflows are bound to a list and run against each item so typically the workflow can be started one of three ways (manually, created, or modified) and users usually need some sort of edit/contribute permission level to kick it off.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69599/discussion-on-answer-by-chris-g-what-permissions-to-grant-power-users-on-tasks-l).